# The gridlines appear dimmed

Tags: plotting

After running the code:

```
 P1 = Plot3D[Cot[x - y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
Export["example.png", P1]
```

I get the figure:

[image]

As you see gridlines on the axis are visible. But when I add `ImageResolution -> 900`, gridlines appear dimmed.

```
 Export["example2.png", P1, ImageResolution -> 900]
```

[image]

How to set options for gridlines in order to make more visible?

Comment: Try to add the option `FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[{Black, Thin, Dashing -> None}]`. Hope this helps.